# Webpack error: error TS2305: Module '"angular2/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'

Tags: webpack, angular

I am starting to play with Angular 2 and Webpack but keep getting error of

```
    ERROR in C:\msweb\ng2Boilerplate\src\comps\myip\Myip.ts
(8,9): error TS2305: Module '"angular2/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.

ERROR in C:\msweb\ng2Boilerplate\src\comps\digg\DiggLoader.ts
(3,9): error TS2305: Module '"angular2/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.

ERROR in C:\msweb\ng2Boilerplate\src\comps\app2\App2.ts
(19,9): error TS2305: Module '"angular2/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.

ERROR in C:\msweb\ng2Boilerplate\src\comps\app1\App1.ts
(3,9): error TS2305: Module '"angular2/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

and my file for example are also standard as in:

```
    ///<reference path="../../../typings/app.d.ts" />

import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {Consts} from "../../Conts";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import {AsyncSubject} from "rxjs/subject/AsyncSubject";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
//import {JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp} from 'angular2/http';

interface IIpAddress {
    ip: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'MyIp',
```

with latest Angular 2 beta.0

this is my Bootstrap, basic:

```
bootstrap(App, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
provide(CommBroker, {useClass: CommBroker}),
provide(Consts, {useClass: Consts}),
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

my webpack config is pretty vanilla... is this a bug in latest ng2 not exporting headers? Google doesn't seem to know

tx

Sean

Comment: Plz add details of your file which is throwing this error

Comment: Can you also post how you bootstrap the app, and the scripts you add in the `index.html`

Comment: here is the project with the issue: https://github.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplater-webpack